# window.open jquery variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, window.open

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var link = $('#unique_link').html();
var vk_link = "http://vk.com/share.php?url="+link+"&amp;title=text";
</script>

<a onclick="window.open(vk_link,'_blank', 'scrollbars=0, resizable=1, menubar=0, left=100, top=100, width=550, height=440, toolbar=0, status=0');return false">LINK</a>
```

But in browser I see undefined, not replaced variable: `window.open(vk_link, ....`
How to fix it?

Comment: Also, make sure you're running this code after the DOM has actually rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to access `vk_link` in a string which will not be evaluated to its value. Just define a function let's say `openWindow` and call it on `onClick` instead like below.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var link = $('#unique_link').html();
var vk_link = "http://vk.com/share.php?url="+link+"&amp;title=text";

function openWindow(){
    window.open(vk_link,'_blank', 'scrollbars=0, resizable=1, menubar=0, left=100, top=100, width=550, height=440, toolbar=0, status=0');
}
</script>

<a onclick="openWindow()">LINK</a>
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the HREF attribute with javascript: keyword in Anchor Tag to call a JavaScript function:

```
<a href="javascript:window.open(vk_link,'_blank', 'scrollbars=0, .......">Link</a>
```